# Aplicação Laravel 4 não escreve em arquivos

Tags: linux, apache, laravel-4, centos, permissões

Tenho um servidor Apache instalado no Sistema Operacional CentOS 7 e uma aplicação construída através do Framework Laravel 4.2, já alterei as permissões dos diretórios do sistema com o comando:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

Porém ainda assim a aplicação não esta conseguindo escrever em seus diretórios, retornando o seguinte erro:

[image: Mensagem de erro ao rodar aplicação no navegador]

Não entendo o porquê de não estar funcionando, as permissões de escrita foram dadas aos diretórios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o que estava bloqueando os acessos a escrita nos diretórios, trata-se do **SELinux**, uma implementação da arquitetura **MAC** (Mandatory Access Control) para o Linux que *provê políticas de segurança* sobre todos os processos.

Então é necessário **informar** ao **SELinux** o diretório que o Apache estará utilizando com o comando:

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/Questionnaire/app/storage
```

O Apache deve ser capaz de escrever no diretório storage sem problemas.

---

Ainda que **não recomendado** (por motivos de segurança), é possível também **desabilitar** o **SELinux**, seguindo os passos abaixo:

**01.** Verificar o status do SELinux.

```
$ sestatus
```

**02.** Desabilitar o SELinux apenas na sessão atual.

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

**03.** Desabilitar o SELinux permanentemente.

**03.01.** Abra para edição o arquivo de configuração do SELinux

```
$ sudo vi /etc/selinux/config
```

**03.02.** Modifique a definição **SELINUX** para **disabled**.

**SELINUX=disabled**

**03.03.** Salve o arquivo e reinicie o sistema operacional

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

**03.04.** Após reiniciar verifique o status do SELinux, deve constar como disabled.

---

Referências:

1. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/
2. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux
3. https://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-centos/
4. http://gesielbernardes.eti.br/configurar-selinux.html